# Navigate between angular and other routes on express

Tags: angular, express

If I open an incognito window and go straight to `myurl.com/test` I get back `Hello this is test` as I should. As soon as I visit `myurl.com` for the first time and my angular page loads, I am never able to return to `myurl.com/test`, it seems I am trapped in the angular app? When I type in `myurl.com/test` the screen goes blank and the endpoint on the server is never hit.

`server.js`

```
const { mongoose } = require('./database/db');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

const path = require('path');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

var userController = require('./controllers/userController');

app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, () => console.log('Server started at port : ' + port));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api/user', userController);

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  console.log('sad face!');
  res.send('Hello this is test');

});

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'angular')));
```

I'm not sure if this is helpful but this is the routes form angular, I've tried changing the `''` path but that did nothing

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user/user.component';
import { OverviewComponent } from './messenger/overview/overview.component';
import { CompanyProfileComponent } from './user/company-profile/company-profile.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'company',
    component: CompanyProfileComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'messenger',
    component: OverviewComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'messenger/:id',
    component: OverviewComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'messenger/archive/:id',
    component: OverviewComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you going to do with NodeJs server in angular ?.
Routes in angular Hane not rapport with your Server routes.
Try to call you Server.js routes in Call Api in service in Angular.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. My NodeJS server serves my angular app on AWS. It also serves other things and I'm having trouble reaching the other things.

Answer (score 0):

You must build your angular project to get the build file in the ./dist filles. after this you can return the index.html files in your nodeJs Server.

Comment: Yeah I had no problem getting the angular folder. It looks like the Angular Service worker was just blocking some URLs

Answer (score 0):

First time when you load the application then it hit's node server.js file and your test page is opened successfully , As You are using angular It's a SPA (single page application)/ Javascript running at browser end  and changing of routes in Angular is managed at client side (Browser does it behind the scene without hitting server or just push a state in url). No server interaction needed.
Simple like your node js just start the application once and serve to browser, Rest is angular in browser.

**once you are in angular application it will try to resolve every route with it's configuration**

if you want to open your page i guess you must try 
`<a href="htttp://yourdomain/test" > test link </a>` -- href it not the way we use routes in angular, though it will reload your website and open test page.